# Extract Data to CSV but only need first 4 characters - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I currently have a PS script to pull all folder names in a directory and put them into a CSV. This works perfectly. Now I need to extract the same folder names but only have the first 4 characters in the column. Here is my current script:

```
get-childitem $Path -directory | select-object NAME | export-excel -tablename "Projects" -path c:\archive_$date.xlsx
```

It dumps the data that I need, but the current format is 0123-XXXXXXXX. I need to remove everything to the right of the "-" (and in some cases it is an underscore). I found something to add to the script but unfortunately its not working - `$Name.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($Name.Length, 4))`

Comment: What does "its not working" mean?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart -- sorry, shouldve been more specific. I get the following

`
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-childitem $Path -directory | select-object NAME | export-excel -t ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very cool feature of the `Select-Object` command which can solve this problem for you.  It's called Calculated Properties, and you use it like so.

Given a directory that looks like this:

```
get-childitem -directory | Select-Object -first 5 -ExpandProperty Name
amd_chipset_drivers_am4
Fusion364
gaming_app_6
Italian love songs (Instrumental) (musicfromrizzo)
mindustry-windows-64-bit
```

You can generate new columns using this syntax:

```
Select-Object @{Name=‘TitleOfNewColumn‘;Expression=#PowerShellCodeHere}}
```

In practice:

```
get-childitem -directory | Select-Object `
    @{Name=‘FullName‘;Expression={$_.BaseName}},`
    @{Name=‘FourCharacters’;Expression={$_.BaseName.SubString(0,4)}} 

FullName                                           FourCharacters
--------                                           --------------
amd_chipset_drivers_am4                            amd_          
Fusion364                                          Fusi          
gaming_app_6                                       gami          
Italian love songs (Instrumental) (musicfromrizzo) Ital          
mindustry-windows-64-bit                           mind
```

Now, simply pipe that into your `Export-Csv` command and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question properly, you need the leftmost 4 characters of the directory names, but if that contains a `-` or `_`, you need the left part preceeding that character.

If that is the case, try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory | 
Select-Object @{Name = 'Prefix'; Expression = {($_.Name.Substring(0,4) -split '[-_]')[0]}} |
Export-Excel -Path "c:\archive_$date.xlsx" -TableName "Projects"
```

Examples:

```
    0123-XXXXXXXX   --> 0123
    013_YYYYYYYYYY  --> 013
    1-_4-ZZZZZZZZZ  --> 1
```

<sup>make sure the `$Path` variable holds a valid root path and that `$date` is formatted in a way so that there are no illegal filename characters in there like `\` or `:`</sup>